# Expressão regular para encontrar barra

Tags: html5, regex, validator

Preciso validar um campo e o mesmo deve possuir o seguinte formato: duas_letras/números. Ex.: RN/1234567. As duas letras serão sempre maiúsculas e a quantidade de números não tem limite.

Comment: Acho que seria algo como `/[A-Z]{2}\/[0-9]{1,}/`.

Comment: Os dois números serão sempre maiúsculos? Melhor editar isso para duas letras senão não vai ter resposta certa :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sou muito bom em Regex, mas acho que esse serve pra você:

```
[A-Z]{2}[\/][0-9]{1,}
```

Explicação:

- `[A-Z]{2}`:Encontra dois caracteres de A até Z
- `[\/]`: Encontra uma barra
- `[1-9]{1,}`: Encontra de 1 até infinitos números

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, meu caro.

Comment: Nessa sua Regex o zero foi excluido?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo obrigado pela observação

Answer (score 4):

Em geral, se quiser validar se existem duas letras, maiúsculas, seguidas de uma barra e depois somente números, sem tamanho específico pode usar:

```
[A-Z]{2}\/[0-9]{1,}
```

Isso vai fazer com que seja válido doos caracteres entre A e Z. Depois uma barra, escapada, para exigir que exista a barra após as duas letras. Depois verifica existência de números, entre 0 até 9, ao menos deve existir um número até o infinito.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, meu caro.

Comment: Mesmo que tenha sido via comentário você foi o primeiro a responder. Up dado

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução: `str.match(/\w{2}\/\d+/g)`

- `\w{2}` qualquer letra (**w**ord) 2 vezes
- `\/` uma barra `/`
- `\d+` qualquer digito (**d**igit) 1 ou mais vezes

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar as respostas acima, para utilizar a expressão regular explicado acima você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**PHP**

```
$codigo = 'RN/1234567';

$regex = '~[A-Z]{2}\/[1-9]{1,}~';

if (preg_match($regex, $codigo)) {
    echo 'Código válido!';
}  else {
     echo 'Insira um código válido!';
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var codigo = 'RN/1234560';
var regex = /[A-Z]{2}\/[1-9]{1,}/g;
if (regex.test(codigo)) {
    console.log('Código válido!');
} else {
    console.log('Insira um código válido!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Com Javascript, você pode fazer assim:

```
function validarMeuCampo(texto) {
    var captura = texto.match(/[A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9]+/);
    var valido = !!captura && captura.length == 1 && captura[0].length == texto.length;
    return valido;
}
```

Explicação:

A expressão regular `/[A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9]+/` captura duas letras maiúsculas, seguidas de uma barra, seguida de uma quantidade de números. A quantidade de números é ilimitada, mas deve haver pelo menos um número (é isso que o `+` à direita dos números faz).

O método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) do tipo String recebe uma expressão regular e retorna um array de porções da String para a qual a expressão encontrou algo. Caso não encontre nada, retorna nulo.

O operador `!` faz uma negação. Ocorre que em Javascript **tudo** é negável. Negar duas vezes é uma forma de descobrir se uma variável que deveria ser um objeto tem valor, pois a negação de um objeto é falso, e a negação de nulo é verdadeiro. Em outras palavras: o contrário do meu contrário é um valor booleano que me diz se eu tenho valor ou não.

Juntando tudo agora: encontre no texto informado trechos que batam com a expressão regular. Se você encontrar um único resultado que seja igual a string, então a string é válida para a sua regra.